How to make a preview window for the camera while recording on Android using Delphi
I am working on code to record from my camera and I need a preview window for the camera while recording in sample TImage:
`texture := TJSurfaceTexture.JavaClass.init(1);
　　surface := TJSurface.JavaClass.init(texture);

　　recorder := TJMediaRecorder.Create();

　　recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
　　recorder.setAudioSource(TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.CAMCORDER);
　　recorder.setVideoSource(TJMediaRecorder_VideoSource.JavaClass.CAMERA);
　　recorder.setOutputFormat(TJMediaRecorder_OutputFormat.JavaClass.MPEG_4);
　　recorder.setAudioEncoder(TJMediaRecorder_AudioEncoder.JavaClass.DEFAULT);
　　recorder.setVideoEncoder(TJMediaRecorder_VideoEncoder.JavaClass.H264);
　　recorder.setMaxDuration(1800000); // 30 minutes
　　recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
　　recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
　　filename:=System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedCameraPath+'/abc0002.mp4';
　　recorder.setOutputFile(StringToJString(FILENAME));
　　recorder.prepare();

　　recorder.start();`

I am trying to add TImage in my form, but how to view the camera while recording? I am using Delphi 10.3 and I'm new to Delphi programming.
